# Change Android boot splash screen (not bootanimation.zip)

Tags: android, boot-animation

When my android device turns on, an image and after that a video is shown. I've searched a lot about boot animation and boot video but all answers I've found were about `bootanimation.zip` file. And my problem is that there was no file in `system/media/bootanimation.zip` path. I tried to create a new file, but nothing changed with boot video.

I've searched in the device and found a file here: `system/etc/bootvideo`. after I replaced the file with my own video it was changed very well. But there is a problem that before the video starts still showing an image that I couldn't find it yet! Where can I change that image ?

Comment: That image is probably being shown by the bootloader.

Comment: Where is bootloader? May I read it and find where the image is ?

Answer (score 0):

The image you see is probably the splash screen included in your system boot. Change this is not as straightforward as changing the boot video and its location and method to modify may vary depending on your system manufacturer and model.

You can find some guides here:

- Snapdragon devices (and a little workaround for Mediatek): https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/guide-how-to-create-custom-boot-logo-t3470473
- PX30/Rockchip: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224916/change-android-bootloader-splash-screen-image

Be very careful using those methods. You could brick your device if something goes wrong.